# Why is this giving an AttributeError? (Accessing class attribute in Python)

Tags: python, attributes, stack, attributeerror, abstract-data-type

I have the following implementation of a Stack:

```
class Stack:
    len = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.len = 0

    # isEmpty() - returns True if stack is empty and false otherwise
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []
    # push() - Insert item at the top of the stack
    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)
        self.len = self.len + 1

    # pop() - Remove and return element from top of the stack,
    # provided it is not empty
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
        self.len = self.len - 1

    # also known as peek() - return top element from stack without removing,
    #
    def top(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]
```

When i try to access the `len` attribute in main() it gives an Attribute Error....

```
import ADT as ADT
def main():
    stack = ADT.Stack()
    print (stack)
```

```
AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'len'
```

What's going on? I tried getattr() and that fails too.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the code shown. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Take note that there is no need to store the length of the stack – you can just get it as ``len(self.items)``. It is also useless for its only usage shown – ``self.items[len(self.items)-1]`` should just be ``self.items[-1]`` instead. Likewise, ``isEmpty`` should just test ``not self.items`` instead of ``self.items == []``.

Comment: Not to mention, the code for maintaining that length is wrong; `self.len = self.len - 1` can't happen, because the `return` bails out of `pop` first.